# Mongoose - find() - based on variable

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to find records based on a parameter passed to my express.

I want to find all the documents in a collection, and if the param is present, I want to find documents based on the param.

I know what I did is not even close to right, but it works.
I just want to know what the correct way of doing it is.

What I have:

```
const offset = 0;
const limit = 10;
const itemName = req.query.itemName;

let searchQuery = '';
if(itemName && itemName !== 'undefined' && itemName !== ''){
    searchQuery = { item: { "$regex": String(itemName), "$options": "i" }}
} else {
    searchQuery = { userRef: String(id) };
};

return MyModel
.find(searchQuery)
.limit(limit)
.skip(offset)
.then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({ result: result })
}
```

EDIT:
The issue I am running into is what if I want to add more search queries, and maybe combine more than one query.
I did some more digging, I figured that maybe I should aggregate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have found the solution.

I had to use the mongoose `$and` and `$or` operator.

My final code looks like this:

```
MyModel.find({
        $and: [
            { ref: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) },
            { $and: [
                { query1: { $regex: String(query1), $options: "i" }  },
                { query2: { $regex: String(query2), $options: "i" }  },
                { query3: { $regex: String(query3), $options: "i" }  }
            ]}
        ]
    })
```

So now all of the fields are being searched when the API is called